# Why my own external IP doesn't work for me?

Tags: external, ip

After setting up static IP and port forwarding, I ran my servlet and replaced "localhost" with my external IP [ got from http://portforward.com/ ], but it failed to get any info from my servlet, why ?

I thought if I use "localhost", the browser just gets the info from my own PC without getting onto the Internet, basically a local trip, and if I use external IP, it sees it as an outside address, go to my ISP, trys to connect to this "external IP", and it just happens to be my own machine, so it talks to my servlet from outside and gets the info, but that doesn't seem the case, how come ?

Comment: First you claim it failed to connect to your external IP and in the second paragraph it sounds like you are able to connect but retrieving the same information as if you connect to `localhost`. *What exactly is your problem now?*

Comment: Many IP stacks are smart enough to notice "Hey, that's on my IP subnet, I don't need to send it to a router, Oh not only is it on my subnet, but it's *me* so I'll not even bother the NIC driver with it and just pass it back up my stack as if I received it from the NIC".

Comment: @Felix : In the second paragraph I said "I thought" it should work that way, but it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Most NAT routers only do port forwarding on traffic coming in through the WAN port.  Traffic generated locally won't be eligible for the NAT rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a firewall blocking incoming traffic to port 80 (or whatever port you happen to be running your web server on). It's either blocked by a firewall internal to your system or your ISP is blocking it or both. Odds are high that your ISP simply won't allow any incoming traffic on port 80 on their run-of-the-mill internet access plan. They don't want you hosting websites from your house. They would rather you purchase a hosting plan.

Comment: The port is 8080, and I tested to send Paypal IPN messages from it's web site test tool to my external IP and I got the messages from my servlet, which means the port wasn't blocked, while Paypal could talk to my servlet with this external IP, why can't I ?